# Pandas Pivot table Output has Integer and Float

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

```
student.pivot_table(
    values="Marks",
    index="Student Name",
    columns="Subject",
    margins=True,
    aggfunc="mean"     
)
```

With `margin=True`, the output for one column is integer and rest all is float.

[image: Output with margin=True]

With `margin=False`, the output of all the columns is integer.

[image: Output with margin=False]

Comment: Check default data types of columns. margins = True will 
Add all row / columns (e.g. for subtotal / grand totals).

Comment: dtype of the column marks is int64

Comment: I think it seems logical that if you are going to calculate a mean pandas change the data type to float.. you can use .astype(float) or .astype(int) at the end

Comment: My question is why one of the column is not float and all other columns are float. Please check the attached image. And this happens only when i add the margin=True. If margin=False, all the output values are int64